# Add each element of a vector as new column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

If a vector has 5 elements, I need to add 5 columns to my `data.table`.
My first new column has for unique value the element 1 of my vector.

This is something I can do with a `for`, as in my reprex below :

```
foo <- data.table(col1 = 1:10, col2 = sample(letters[1:5], replace = TRUE))

fun.add <- function(DT) {
  
  v1 <- c(3, 5.5, 9)
  v2 <- c("x", "y", "z")
  
  for (j in 1:3) {
    DT[, paste0("aaa", j) := v1[j]]
    DT[, paste0("bbb", j) := v2[j]]
  }
  
  # DT[, paste0("aaa", 1:3),  := ...]
}

fun.add(foo)
```

I would prefer to do it without the `for` and rather like in the comment line.
In this case, I can't use `lapply` and `.SD` ...
Is there a way to ? Another way ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this more efficiently instead of doing this in a `for` loop i.e. convert the vectors to a `list` with `as.list` and create the columns by assignment (`:=`) to the vector of column names created with `paste` (`paste` is vectorized)

```
foo[, paste0("aaa", seq_along(v1)) := as.list(v1)]
foo[, paste0("bbb", seq_along(v2)) := as.list(v2)]
```

---

If we wrap it in a function

```
fun.add <- function(DT) {
     v1 <- c(3, 5.5, 9)
     v2 <- c("x", "y", "z")
     DT[, paste0("aaa", seq_along(v1)) := as.list(v1)]
     DT[, paste0("bbb", seq_along(v2)) := as.list(v2)][]
    return(DT)
}
```

-testing

```
> fun.add(foo)
    col1 col2 aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3
 1:    1    a    3  5.5    9    x    y    z
 2:    2    e    3  5.5    9    x    y    z
 3:    3    d    3  5.5    9    x    y    z
 4:    4    c    3  5.5    9    x    y    z
 5:    5    b    3  5.5    9    x    y    z
 6:    6    a    3  5.5    9    x    y    z
 7:    7    e    3  5.5    9    x    y    z
 8:    8    d    3  5.5    9    x    y    z
 9:    9    c    3  5.5    9    x    y    z
10:   10    b    3  5.5    9    x    y    z
```

Comment: Secretly waiting for your answer @akrun, here it is !
I like to use ```paste0``` for creating columns, I forgot assignment ```:=``` need ```list```, while this is basic...

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution.

**INPUT:**

```
v1  <- c(3, 5.5, 9)
v2  <- c("x", "y", "z")
foo <- data.table(col1 = 1:10, col2 = sample(letters[1:5], replace = TRUE))

N_col0 <- NCOL(foo) # used later on to redefine column class
```

**CODE:**

```
v12 <- c(rbind(v1, v2))
m12 <- matrix(rep(v12, each = NROW(foo)), NROW(foo))
foo <- cbind(foo, m12)
numeric_col <- grep("[0-9]", v12) + N_col0
for(j in numer_col){set(foo, j=j, value=as.numeric(foo[[j]]))}
```

**CODE EXPLAINED:**

1.Combine v1 & v2.

```
v12 <- c(rbind(v1, v2)) # note it is a character vector

print(v12)
[1] "3"   "x"   "5.5" "y"   "9"   "z"
```

2.Create a character matrix of v12. You can set column names at this stage if you like.

```
m12 <- matrix(rep(v12, each = NROW(foo)), NROW(foo))

print(v12)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,] "3"  "x"  "5.5" "y"  "9"  "z" 
 [2,] "3"  "x"  "5.5" "y"  "9"  "z" 
 [3,] "3"  "x"  "5.5" "y"  "9"  "z" 
 [4,] "3"  "x"  "5.5" "y"  "9"  "z" 
 [5,] "3"  "x"  "5.5" "y"  "9"  "z" 
 [6,] "3"  "x"  "5.5" "y"  "9"  "z" 
 [7,] "3"  "x"  "5.5" "y"  "9"  "z" 
 [8,] "3"  "x"  "5.5" "y"  "9"  "z" 
 [9,] "3"  "x"  "5.5" "y"  "9"  "z" 
[10,] "3"  "x"  "5.5" "y"  "9"  "z"
```

3.cBind foo & m12.

```
foo<- cbind(foo, m12)

print(foo)
    col1 col2 V1 V2  V3 V4 V5 V6
 1:    1    b  3  x 5.5  y  9  z
 2:    2    d  3  x 5.5  y  9  z
 3:    3    d  3  x 5.5  y  9  z
 4:    4    e  3  x 5.5  y  9  z
 5:    5    d  3  x 5.5  y  9  z
 6:    6    b  3  x 5.5  y  9  z
 7:    7    d  3  x 5.5  y  9  z
 8:    8    d  3  x 5.5  y  9  z
 9:    9    e  3  x 5.5  y  9  z
10:   10    d  3  x 5.5  y  9  z
```

4.All new columns are character columns. To fix this we can detect what elements in the vector 12 are numeric and use the function set of data table.

```
foo[, lapply(.SD, class)]

      col1      col2        V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6
1: integer character character character character character character character


numeric_col <- grep("[0-9]", v12) + N_col0
for(j in numer_col){set(foo, j=j, value=as.numeric(foo[[j]]))}

foo[, lapply(.SD, class)]

  col1      col2      V1        V2      V3        V4      V5        V6
1: integer character numeric character numeric character numeric character
```

Comment: Need benchmark. Not sure it's more efficient than staying in ```data.table```.